# Modify SVG file using document mouse click in Java

Tags: java, dom, svg, dom-events, batik

I need to modify and work with a SVG map file using Batik, but I am not able to modify it. What I am struggling to do is to modify the fill color value of a country (which I am able to get from the path element after parsing the SVG file). For this I need to figure out which country is clicked to get its id of other identifier to modify the correct fill parameter.

Here is my code:

```
public class SVGEditor{
    public File svgEditFile;
    public SVGDocument svgDoc;
    public JSVGCanvas svgCanvas;
    public SAXSVGDocumentFactory svgDocumentFactory;
    public Document doc;
    public Vector<String> colors = new Vector<String>();

    public SVGEditor(File f, JSVGCanvas canvas){
        svgEditFile = f;
        svgCanvas = canvas;
        svgCanvas.getInteractors().add(this);
    }

    public void editFile() throws IOException{
        String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
        svgDocumentFactory  = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
        doc = svgDocumentFactory.createDocument(svgEditFile.toURI().toString());

    }
    public void pathParser(){
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList listOfPathNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("path");
        int totalPaths = listOfPathNodes.getLength();
        System.out.println("Total number of paths: " + totalPaths); 
        for(int i = 0; i < totalPaths; i++){
            Element el = (Element) listOfPathNodes.item(i);
            EventTarget target = (EventTarget) el;
            target.addEventListener("click", 
                new org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener() {
                    public void handleEvent(org.w3c.dom.events.Event evt) {
                        if(evt.getType().equals("click")){
                            //Here is where I want to get the clicked path from the interaction with the DOM document
                            Element el  = (Element)evt.getTarget();
                            System.out.println("Clicked Path:" + el.getElementsByTagname("path");

                         }
                     }


                 }, false);
             // Get id data
             id = el.getAttribute("id");
             // Get path data
             String path = el.getAttribute("d");
             if(id.equals("ro"))
                 System.out.println(path);
             addPoint(path);

             // Get color data
             String style = el.getAttribute("style");
             int index1 = style.indexOf("fill:#");
             String color = style.substring((index1+5),(index1 + 12));
             colors.add((id + ":" +color));

         }
     }
 }
```

Here is the SVG file: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b3/Blank_map_of_Europe.svg  and you can use 
this link directly in the `editFile()` method.

I hope it is easy to understand that what I want to do is to find where to modify the fill color value on the document using the click event using this solution or other solutions from you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the country id you clicked on, you should register `mousedown` event listener.
(`click` doesn't work on my version of batik)

If you want to find out on which country you clicked:

```
@Override
public void handleEvent(Event e) {
    Element element = (Element) e.getCurrentTarget();

    String countryISO = element.getAttribute("id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled too with such a problem for a few long hours. I finally found it ! In fact I think you only lack this statement:

```
svgCanvas.setDocumentState(JSVGCanvas.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC);
```

I uploaded my solution to github, it's available here: https://github.com/fmarot/miscPOC/tree/master/batik-poc1 
By the way, with Batik 1.7 (what I tried), "click" does work ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have something changed in your Code.

```
    public class SVGEditor {
    public File svgEditFile;
    public SVGDocument svgDoc;
    public JSVGCanvas svgCanvas;
    public SAXSVGDocumentFactory svgDocumentFactory;
    public Document doc;
    public Vector<String> colors = new Vector<String>();

    public SVGEditor(File f, JSVGCanvas canvas){
        svgEditFile = f;
        svgCanvas = canvas;
        svgCanvas.getInteractors().add(this);
    }

    public void editFile() throws IOException{
        String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
        svgDocumentFactory  = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
        doc = svgDocumentFactory.createDocument(svgEditFile.toURI().toString());

    }
    public void pathParser(){
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList listOfPathNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("path");
        int totalPaths = listOfPathNodes.getLength();
        System.out.println("Total number of paths: " + totalPaths); 
        for(int i = 0; i < totalPaths; i++){
            Element el = (Element) listOfPathNodes.item(i);
            EventTarget target = (EventTarget) el;
            target.addEventListener("click", 
                new org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener() {
                    public void handleEvent(org.w3c.dom.events.Event evt) {
                        if(evt.getType().equals("click")){
                            //Here is where I want to get the clicked path from the interaction with the DOM document
                            Element el  = (Element)evt.getTarget();
                            System.out.println("Clicked Path:" + el.getElementsByTagName("path"));

                         }
                     }


                 }, false);
             // Get id data
             String id = el.getAttribute("id");
             // Get path data
             String path = el.getAttribute("d");
             if(id.equals("ro"))
                 System.out.println(path);

             // Get color data
             String style = el.getAttribute("style");
             int index1 = style.indexOf("fill:#");
             String color = style.substring((index1+5),(index1 + 12));
             colors.add((id + ":" +color));

         }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("SVG start");

        JSVGCanvas canvas = new JSVGCanvas();
        canvas.setDocumentState(JSVGCanvas.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC);
        SVGEditor svgEditor = new SVGEditor(new File(
                "C:\\Users\\neda.danilovic\\Desktop\\batik 1.7\\miscPOC-master\\batik-poc1\\src\\main\\java\\glasspane\\Blank_map_of_Europe.svg"), canvas);
        svgEditor.editFile();
        svgEditor.pathParser();
        System.out.println("SVG end");
    }
}


package glasspane;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory;
import org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGDOMImplementation;
import org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGOMSVGElement;
import org.apache.batik.swing.JSVGCanvas;
import org.apache.batik.swing.svg.AbstractJSVGComponent;
import org.apache.batik.util.XMLResourceDescriptor;
import org.w3c.dom.DOMImplementation;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.events.Event;
import org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener;
import org.w3c.dom.events.EventTarget;
import org.w3c.dom.svg.SVGSVGElement;

public class SvgGlassPaneExample {

    private JSVGCanvas  canvas;
    private JLabel      target;
    private SAXSVGDocumentFactory svgDocumentFactory;
    private Document doc;
    private File svgEditFile;
    private Vector<String> colors = new Vector<String>();

    /** Creates a new instance of SvgGlassPaneExample 
     * @throws IOException */
    public SvgGlassPaneExample(JPanel panel) throws IOException {
        panel.removeAll();
        canvas = new JSVGCanvas();
        canvas.setDocumentState(AbstractJSVGComponent.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC);
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\neda.danilovic\\Desktop\\batik 1.7\\miscPOC-master\\batik-poc1\\src\\main\\java\\glasspane\\Blank_map_of_Europe.svg");
        String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
        svgDocumentFactory  = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
        canvas.setDocument(svgDocumentFactory.createDocument(file.toURI().toString()));
        panel.add(canvas);
        panel.repaint();
    }

    public void addGlassPane() {
        String svgNS = SVGDOMImplementation.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI;
        Document doc = canvas.getSVGDocument();
        Element rectangle = doc.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
        rectangle.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "0");
        rectangle.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "0");
        rectangle.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "700");
        rectangle.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "700");
        rectangle.setAttributeNS(null, "style", "fill:none;pointer-events:fill");
        rectangle.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "glasspane");
        Element svgRoot = doc.getDocumentElement();

        svgRoot.insertBefore(rectangle, doc.getElementById("rectangles"));

    }

    public void registerListeners(JLabel target) {
        //this label provides feedback on the selected item
        this.target = target;
        // Gets an element from the loaded document.
        // document is your SVGDocument

        NodeList listOfPathNodes = canvas.getSVGDocument().getElementsByTagName("path");
        int totalPaths = listOfPathNodes.getLength();
        System.out.println("Total number of paths: " + totalPaths); 
        for(int i = 0; i < totalPaths; i++){
            Element el = (Element) listOfPathNodes.item(i);
            EventTarget eventTarget = (EventTarget) el;
            eventTarget.addEventListener("click", 
                new EventListener() {
                    public void handleEvent(Event evt) {
                        System.out.println("click happend!!!");
                     }
                 }, false);

             // Get id data
             String id = el.getAttribute("id");
             // Get path data
             String path = el.getAttribute("d");
             if(id.equals("ro"))
                 System.out.println(path);

             // Get color data
             String style = el.getAttribute("style");
             int index1 = style.indexOf("fill:#");
             String color = style.substring((index1+5),(index1 + 12));
             colors.add((id + ":" +color));

         }
    }

    public class GlassPaneClick implements EventListener {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event evt) {
            target.setText("Glasspane event " + ((Element) evt.getTarget()).getAttribute("id"));
            target.repaint();
        }
    }

    public class ObjectClick implements EventListener {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event evt) {
            target.setText("Rectangles event " + ((Element) evt.getTarget()).getAttribute("id"));
            target.repaint();
        }
    }

    public void makeDocument() throws IOException{
        String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
        svgDocumentFactory  = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
        doc = svgDocumentFactory.createDocument(svgEditFile.toURI().toString());

    }
}

How to make that click on SVG works?
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what you've changed.